# change div tag of jsp page from a java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jms

I am using **Servlet and JSP** for a web chat application. To send and receive messages I am using  **JMS**. Now when I send a particular message there is a listener class in java who receives the message. My problem is that I am unable to post the message on the JSP page without reloading it. Can you please tell me how to change the particular **div tag** of the JSP page from that java  class.

Comment: use javascript with ajax.

Comment: Can I be able to retrieve the string from the java class on that page using javascript or ajax

Comment: That's not how you would use ajax. You'll use it to send an HTTP request to some servlet that will respond only with that String. Which you can then use to replace the content of the `div` tag.

Comment: Sorry sir, I don't think that it will be help full, because i can't send the request manually as I don't know when a message is going to come. Message is received automatically in the java class and as soon as the message is received the message must be posted on the JSP page.

Comment: You are mixing up concepts. A `jsp` is rendered and sent as the body of the HTTP response. That's what your client (ex. browser) will see. Once the response is sent, the `jsp`'s job is finished. You can use ajax to poll for new messages. Or use server push.

Comment: Thankyou sir, I think server push might be applicable for me.